# Tcl loop idea: for_index_item

Tags: tcl

I often need to loop through a list of items and need both the index position, and the item itself:

```
set names {John Paul George Ringo}
set i 0
foreach name $names {
    puts "$i - $name"
    incr i
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 0 - John
> 1 - Paul
> 2 - George
> 3 - Ringo
> ```

Since I frequently do this, I decided to implement my own loop and call it `for_item_index` for lack of creativity. Here is my loop and a short code segment to test it:

```
proc for_index_item {index item iterable body } {
    uplevel 1 set $index 0
    foreach x $iterable {
        uplevel 1 set $item $x
        uplevel 1 $body
        uplevel 1 incr $index
    }
}

# Test it
set names {John Paul George Ringo}
for_index_item i name $names {
    puts "$i - $name"
}
```

I have tested it with `break`, and `continue` and found my new loop performs as expected. My concern is the excessive use of `uplevel` command in the code. I am seeking reviewers to give me tips for improving it.

Here are my own review of my code:

- Excessive use of `uplevel`
- The index always starts at zero. There are times when I want it to start at 1 or some other values. To add that feature, I will probably introduce another parameter, `startValue`
- Likewise, the index always get incremented by 1. The user might want to increment it by a different values such as 2, or -1 to count backward. Again, introducing another parameter, `step` might help, but at this point, the loop is getting complicated.

Comment: Here's a bit more concise way to "Break down indexexpr": `lassign $indexexpr idxvar start step; if {$start == ""} {set start 0}; if {$step == ""} {set step 1}` (shame about comment code formatting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would base something like this on `for` rather than `foreach`

```
proc foreach_with_index {idxvar elemvar list body args} {
    array set opts {-start 0 -inc 1}
    if {[llength $args] > 0 && [llength $args]%2 == 0} {array set opts $args}
    upvar 1 $idxvar idx
    upvar 1 $elemvar elem
    for {set idx $opts(-start)} {$idx < [llength $list]} {incr idx $opts(-inc)} {
        set elem [lindex $list $idx]
        uplevel 1 $body
    }
}
```

So you get

```
% foreach_with_index i e {a b c d e} {puts "$i - $e"}
0 - a
1 - b
2 - c
3 - d
4 - e
% foreach_with_index i e {a b c d e} {puts "$i - $e"} -start 1 -inc 2
1 - b
3 - d
```

Some thoughts:

- don't forget about `upvar` to link a variable up the call stack.
- I chose to use Tk style `-options` for some reason. It looks a bit awkward, but it's not exactly pretty to have to jam arguments at the end. You might choose to arguments with default values for `start` and `inc`. Or you might decide to put optional arguments in the middle of the list somewhere (like the way `puts` has an optional filehandle as the 1st arg), but that's more work to parse the arguments.
- in hindsight, using `for` vs `foreach` is a pretty arbitrary decision. Here, with `for`, you need to extract the element from the array. With `foreach` you need to increment the index.

Answer (score 1):

"Stealing from python" one could do the following:

```
# enumerate --
#
#       Returns an indexed series: 
#       $startIDX [lindex $inList 0] $startIDX+1 [lindex $inList 1] ...
#
# Arguments:
#       inList    list that should be enumerated
#       startIDX  (optional) where the numbering should start (default=0)

proc enumerate {inList {startIDX 0}} {
    set outList {}
    set i $startIDX
    foreach l $inList {
        lappend outList $i $l
        incr i
    }
    return $outList
}

set names {John Paul George Ringo}
foreach {i n} [enumerate $names] {puts "$i $n"}
```

This avoids `uplevel` and `upvar` completely ...